# how to overlay 3d objects on webcam with opencv and python?

Tags: python, opencv, opengl, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

I want to overlay 3d objects on live webcam for my project. I have overlayed 2d objects like googles, mustache, and hat. Now I want to overlay 3d objects like beard, mustache, and hair. I searched over some articles and tutorials, but all of them were ambiguous and didn't teach where to start. From what I have learned I need to create 3d objects using blender and import it using OpenGL and then somehow overlay it to the facial landmarks. I want to know what I need to learn to achieve this objective. I have read the previous question on this [source1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32210107/opencv-python-opengl-texture) and it didn't help much. Also,  I have read several blogs like [this](https://rdmilligan.wordpress.com/2016/03/19/fruit-machine-using-augmented-reality/comment-page-1/?unapproved=7474&moderation-hash=19d86226a177b69fceda67d49b2a5d11#comment-7474),
[this](https://medium.com/@ahmetozlu93/marker-less-augmented-reality-by-opencv-and-opengl-531b2af0a130), and the best one [here](https://rdmilligan.wordpress.com/2015/10/15/augmented-reality-using-opencv-opengl-and-blender/) and various others while surfing. I know I am entering into AR/VR, but I ready to learn the things required to get my work done.

There are various libraries/frameworks which don't require to code anything like SparkAR, Virtualtryon, ditto, etc. but they don't teach you anything. I want to learn how to do these things by myself. If I create my 3d object like hair(hair-like Goku in SuperSaiyan)/Mustache or eyes in blender how can I overlay it in real-time on webcam using OpenCV or any other python compatible lib/framework? I mean overlaying 3d hair over my own hair, overlaying 3d eyes over my eyes and similar. What are the things required to do such a task? What things do I need to learn?

Comment: you need camera intrinsics, target object 3d pose (cv::solvepnp on landmarks), source object 3d model. If you want take the actual target object geometry into account (instead of a general face model) you have to extract 3d geometry from the image and probably need deep learning for segmentation or understanding

Comment: @Micka Thanks! Can you suggest some good video tutorials?